# Download CSV in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->dbutil();
    $result =  $ci->dbutil->csv_from_result($data);
    $filename = "sample.csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'";'); 
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    foreach ($final_res as $line){ 
        fputcsv($fp,explode(',',$line)); 
    }         
    fclose($fp);          
    exit;
```

I am not able to download the CSV file. I couldn't find any errors. please help

Comment: Where is the code to download?

Comment: this is the function to download the file

Comment: It doesn't download file it puts the CSV into the  php output stream. I would look at the errors set error_reporting(E_ALL) and see whaht happens. You need to provide more information if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use force_download() helper function of CI. [LINK](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing header in your code.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
```